# What to do when meeting your expected professor even before the interview?

Tags: postdocs, interview

I am a postdoc and I have applied to a researcher position in another institute in another country. The story is that I once asked about the position and the professor there replied very positively and asked me to submit my application since my CV meets most of the requirements.

After I submitted my application, I sent a follow-up email informing her that my application has already been submitted. She thanked me and we share a couple of emails around different topics.

Yesterday she asked me if I will be at a conference in my current country and I answered with yes. So, she proposed that she will have a brief chat with me. I believe she will test the water of my skills.

The questions:

1. How good are these meets even before interviews?
2. what is a good approach to show here that I am a good fit? any recommendations?
3. what sort of general questions I might receive?

Thank you!

Comment: Relax and be yourself during the meeting. This is your (and her) chance to find out in advance if you have matching personalities and goals. Be prepared to talk about your past research and your research ideas and goals. However, I doubt her main goal is testing your skills (except for interpersonal and language skills); it's not an exam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for reference to others who might have the same question. The meeting was amazing, we communicated at Dinner, I asked many questions as well as she did the same to me.

In the end, I got questions if I am really interested to join her group..and my answer was yes since I saw she is ambitious, relaxed, open-minded, and collaborative. At the same time, I got semi-confirmation that she will do her best to make me the first option among candidates.

Therefore, my answers would be:

- This type of meetings can really push the candidate acceptance and support forward.
- following up Roland recommendation, be yourself and relaxed.
- Ask your questions, try to see if your future supervisor is collaborative and motivating.

Best